# pollingDuplexHttpBinding with security mode TransportWithMessageCredential. response from server don't come to client

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-security

we use pollingDuplexHttpBinding over SSL with security mode  **TransportWithMessageCredential**.
Service receive messages from client, but client don't get response.

If we change security mode from **TransportWithMessageCredential** to **Transport** all work good.

**Working configuration**

Comments to show don't working config.

Service config

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <!--
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" 
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="myType" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      -->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <pollingDuplexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="multipleMessagesPerPollPollingDuplexHttpBinding"
              duplexMode="SingleMessagePerPoll">
      <!--
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
      -->
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </pollingDuplexHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="Gam.Service.GamSrv">
    <endpoint
        address=""
        binding="pollingDuplexHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="multipleMessagesPerPollPollingDuplexHttpBinding"
        contract="Gam.Service.Abstract.IUserSrv" />
    <endpoint
        address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

SilverLight 4 Client config

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="pd">
      <!--
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
      -->
      <pollingDuplex duplexMode="SingleMessagePerPoll" />
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport transferMode="Buffered" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="/GamSrv.svc"
    binding="customBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="pd"
    contract="GamSrvReference.IUserSrv"
    name="MyDuplexContract" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution - add includeTimestamp="false" in client security config

```
<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false" />
```